# register and login page using tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make a registration/login page using tkinter this way.

```
import tkinter as tk
import pickle 
import pandas as pd
import os

os.chdir(r'D:\\Python Project Vazir\\')

def change_page(prev, next):
    prev.pack_forget()
    next.pack(expand=True, fill='both')

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('550x400')
root.resizable(False, False)
root.title('book store MMW')

loginPage = tk.Frame(root, bg='#F8F8FF')
loginPage.pack(expand=True, fill='both')

pageLabel = tk.Label(loginPage, text="Login or Register", bg='#F8F8FF')
pageLabel.grid(row=0, column=1)

registerNameLabel = tk.Label(loginPage, text="FirstName").grid(row=1, column=0)
registerNameContainer = tk.StringVar()
registerNameField = tk.Entry(loginPage, textvariable=registerNameContainer)
registerNameField.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=3)

registerLastNameLabel = tk.Label(loginPage, text="LastName").grid(row=2, column=0)
registerLastNameContainer = tk.StringVar()
registerLastNameField = tk.Entry(loginPage, textvariable=registerLastNameContainer)
registerLastNameField.grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=3)

registerUsernameLabel = tk.Label(loginPage, text="Username").grid(row=3, column=0)
registerUsernameContainer = tk.StringVar()
registerUsernameField = tk.Entry(loginPage, textvariable=registerUsernameContainer)
registerUsernameField.grid(row=3, column=1, columnspan=3)

registerPasswordLabel = tk.Label(loginPage, text="Password").grid(row=4, column=0)
registerPasswordContainer = tk.StringVar()
registerPasswordField = tk.Entry(loginPage, textvariable=registerPasswordContainer, show="*")
registerPasswordField.grid(row=4, column=1, columnspan=3)

def register(password, username, name, lastname):
    s = pd.Series({'username': username, 'password': password, 'name':name, 'lastname': lastname})
    df = pd.DataFrame(s).T
    if "data" not in os.listdir():
        with open('data', 'wb') as filewriter:
            pickle.dump(obj = df, file = filewriter)
    else:
        with open('data', 'rb') as filereader:
            logins = pickle.load(filereader)
            logins = pd.concat(logins, df)
            logins.reset_index(inplace=True)
            with open('data', 'wb') as filewriter:
                pickle.dump(obj = logins, file = filewriter)            

def validateLogin(username, password, loginPage, mainPage):
    if "data" not in os.listdir():
        dataNotFound = tk.Label(loginPage, text="databaseLost", bg='#F8F8FF')
        dataNotFound.grid(row=6, column=1)
    else:
        with open('data', 'rb') as filereader:
            logins = pickle.load(filereader)
        if username in logins.username.tolist():
            if password == logins[logins.username == username].password.tolist()[0]:
                change_page(loginPage, mainPage)
            else:
                passIncorrect = tk.Label(loginPage, text="passIncorrect", bg='#F8F8FF')
                passIncorrect.grid(row=10, column=1)
        else:
            userNotFound = tk.Label(loginPage, text="userNotFound", bg='#F8F8FF')
            userNotFound.grid(row=10, column=1)

registerButton = tk.Button(loginPage, text="register", command=lambda: register(registerPasswordContainer.get(), registerUsernameContainer.get(), registerNameContainer.get(), registerLastNameContainer.get()))
registerButton.grid(row=5, column=2)

loginrUsernameLabel = tk.Label(loginPage, text="Username").grid(row=7, column=0)
loginUsernameContainer = tk.StringVar()
loginUsernameField = tk.Entry(loginPage, textvariable=registerUsernameContainer)
loginUsernameField.grid(row=7, column=1, columnspan=3)

loginPasswordLabel = tk.Label(loginPage, text="Password").grid(row=8, column=0)
loginPasswordContainer = tk.StringVar()
loginPasswordField = tk.Entry(loginPage, textvariable=registerPasswordContainer, show="*")
loginPasswordField.grid(row=8, column=1, columnspan=3)

loginButton = tk.Button(loginPage, text="Login", command=lambda: validateLogin(loginUsernameContainer.get(), loginPasswordContainer.get(), loginPage, mainPage))
loginButton.grid(row=9, column=2)
```

it keeps saying user not found! seems I cannot retrieve values that I stored in StringVars before (I used varName.get()), Also it seems my login variables are somehow connected to my registration variables! Any help about how can I separate my variables or how can I retrieve variables values?

Comment: first you could use `print()` to see which part of code is executed and what you have in variables.

Comment: see your code - you use the same `registerPasswordContainer` in registration Entry and in login Entry - and `textvariable` automatically update text in Entry when you change value in `StringVar`. You should use `loginUsernameContainer` in login Entry.

Comment: code works for me - I can login after registering.

Comment: thanks to your sharp eyes problem solved buddy! thanks alot